# How to make Ionic scrollbar draggable?

Tags: ionic-framework

I want the user to be able to click and drag the scrollbar on the side of the screen while using my ionic app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the solution was to add isBrowser variable to the controller which determined if this is mobile (no scroll bar) or desktop (draggable scrollbar).

```
<ion-content data-ng-class="{ isBrowserView : appCtrl.isBrowser }"
             overflow-scroll="{{ appCtrl.isBrowser }}">
    ...
</ion-content>
```

And I added the following to me scss file:

```
.isBrowserView {
  overflow-y: auto !important;
}

.isBrowserView .scroll-bar-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```

*If you always want the scrollbar then do not worry about setting the value on a controller. Like so:

```
<ion-content class="isBrowserView"
             overflow-scroll="true">
    ...
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ionic has a built in component called ion-scroll. It does what you have described and more. You can implement it inside your HTML like so.

```
<ion-scroll
             scrollX="true"
             scrollY="true">
</ion-scroll>
```